# Trying to check if a form has "$_POST" anything and echo something if it does

Tags: php, html, forms

I am testing the `isset` and `post` functionality of php. What i want to do is whenever i click the "ADD" button, it'll echo "HELLO". but nothing happen when i click the button. I realize that  `if (isset($_POST['FORM']))` is checking if the form has `$_post` something, so it should be echo-ing "HELLO" right ? But its not working as intended.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['FORM'])){

echo "HELLO";

}   



?>

<html>

<body>  

<form method="post" name="FORM">
    Book Id: <input type="text" name='bookid' /><br/><br/>
    Book Name: <input type="text" name='bookname'  /><br/><br/>
    Borrow Date: <input type="text" name='borrowdate'  /><br/><br/>
    Return Date: <input type="text" name='returndate' /><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="ADD"><br/><br/>
</form> 

</body>
```

Comment: you can't do that.

Comment: What you should check is one of the other names.. $_POST should contains names: bookid, bookname, borrowdate and returndate, to make sure what it has, before the the `isset` use : `print_r($_POST)`. It should contain the information with the keys found in the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<form>` does not use the name attribute, so what you have now won't work.

You need to use the name attributes from the inputs in order to echo what it is you want to pass as a value.

Remove the name attribute from `<form method="post" name="FORM">` and change your `if (isset($_POST['FORM']))` to the POST array(s) while assigning variable to the POST arrays.

Consult the manual on php.net about dealing with forms.

- http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Here is an example pulled from it:

HTML:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
 <p>Your name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
 <p>Your age: <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
Hi <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>.
You are <?php echo (int)$_POST['age']; ?> years old.
```

While using `isset()` / `empty()`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

where `empty()` works best for data input and `isset()` against a submit button that would also need to be named and wrapping everything inside an `isset()` then checking for empty inputs inside that conditional statement.

Comment: Consult the way that [Johannes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47475297/1415724) made the conditional statement and base yourself on that.

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to use

```
if (isset($_POST['bookid']) || isset($_POST['bookname']) || isset($_POST['borrowdate']) || isset($_POST['returndate'])) {

   echo "HELLO";

}
```